# please give me the difference in using export and stdcall keywords for exporting the functions in Dll using delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}
function add(Value1:integer;value2:integer):integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=Value1+value2;
end;

function subtract(Value1:integer;value2:integer):integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=Value2-value1;
end;

function multiply(Value1:integer;value2:integer):integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=Value1*value2;
end;

function divide(Value1:integer;value2:integer):integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=Value2 div value1;
end;

function check(Value1:integer;value2:integer):Boolean;stdcall;
begin
  if(Value2>value1)then
    Result:=True
  else
    Result:=False;
end;

exports add,subtract,multiply,divide,check;
```

this is my dll code. even if i give export it works. may i know the difference between the usage of these two keywords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `export` keyword is a legacy from 16 bit versions. It is ignored in modern versions of Delphi. Do not confuse it with the `exports` directive which is used to specify which functions are exported from a library, and which you use correctly in the code presented.

It doesn't make much sense to compare `export`  with `stdcall`, a calling convention directive, since they are not directly comparable.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. It helped me to find the difference.